# Test Data for Tesseract

Tags: ios, reference, ocr, tesseract, training-data

I have a project which uses Tesseract OCR for IOS. Everything works fine, but I get the following errors:

Failed loading language 'eng'

Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

I have looked everywhere, and I can't find anything I'm doing wrong. I downloaded the test data from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata. I then placed in a folder called "testdata" and dragged it into my project as a folder reference.

Here is a picture of my project: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The folder should be named "tessdata" not "testdata".